# Linear Chart android studio java

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, charts

I have been having trouble with plotting my data onto a linear chart. I am using the `'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'` library.

Here is my current code:

```
    private void displayLinearChart() {
        if (selectedStartDate != null && selectedEndDate != null) {
            ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            Map<String, ArrayList<Entry>> categoryEntries = new HashMap<>();
            DatabaseReference categoriesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Categories").child(currentUserID);

            categoriesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot categorySnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String category = categorySnapshot.getKey();

                        Map<String, Double> dailyTotals = new HashMap<>();

                        for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot : categorySnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Date startDate = Date.from(selectedStartDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
                            Date endDate = Date.from(selectedEndDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
                            Date productDate = null;
                            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                            String dateString = productSnapshot.child("Date").getValue(String.class);

                            try {
                                productDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }

                            // Check if the product falls within the selected date range
                            if (dateString != null && (productDate.equals(startDate) || productDate.after(startDate)) && (productDate.equals(endDate) || productDate.before(endDate))) {
                                Double productAmount = Double.parseDouble(productSnapshot.child("Price").getValue(String.class));
                                String dailyKey = dateFormat.format(productDate);
                                Double dailyTotal = dailyTotals.getOrDefault(dailyKey, 0.0);
                                dailyTotal += productAmount;
                                dailyTotals.put(dailyKey, dailyTotal);

                            }
                            // Add the daily totals to the entry list for this category
                            int i = 0;
                            for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : dailyTotals.entrySet()) {
                                entries.add(new Entry(i++, entry.getValue().floatValue()));
                            }

                            // Add the entry list to the map for this category
                            categoryEntries.put(category, entries);
                        }
                    }
                    LineData lineData = new LineData();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Entry>> entry : categoryEntries.entrySet()) {
                        String category = entry.getKey();
                        ArrayList<Entry> entries = entry.getValue();
                        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, category);
                        lineData.addDataSet(dataSet);
                    }

                    lineChart.setData(lineData);
                    lineChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getDateLabels(selectedStartDate, selectedEndDate)));
                    lineChart.invalidate();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private String[] getDateLabels(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
        LocalDate date = startDate;

        while (!date.isAfter(endDate)) {
            dateList.add(dateFormat.format(Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
            date = date.plusDays(1);
        }

        return dateList.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

The issue is, the data that is being displayed isn't matching up correctly with the correct amount and the correct date. The line that has the number 15 should initially starting at 0 then 1.25 on the 12/4 and then 15 on 13/4

I also don't know why there is a huge gap between 10/04 and 11/04 as there are more dates that need to be displayed.

My goal is to have each category represent a line in the linear chart and it displays how much the user spends per day.

[image]